# Unsure of what's happening in this fraction

Tags: fractions

I can't seem to see what is happening to make this equivalence. More specifically, how the left-side's $n+1$ makes it into the right side's numerator.
$$
\frac {n(n+1)} 2  + (n+1) = \frac {(n+1)(n+2)}2
$$

Comment: Notice that

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n+1 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{2(n+1)}{2}$$

Then you can factor $n+1$ out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:** Factor the $(n+1)$ using distributive property, and note also that $\dfrac{n}{2}+1 = \dfrac{n+2}{2}$